# Is quote necessary when assigning pins in ucf file?

Tags: constraints, verilog, fpga

```
NET "input"  LOC = "N21"

NET "input"  LOC = N21

NET input  LOC = N21
```

Which form is correct?

Answer (score 1):

See the Xilinx [UG625 Constraints Guide](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx14_5/cgd.pdf), **General Rules for UCF and NCF** section.

> Enclose NET and INST names in double quotes (recommended but not
>   mandatory).
>
> Enclose inverted signal names that contain a tilde (for example,
>   ~OUTSIG1) in double quotes (mandatory).
>
> In all of the constraints files (NCF, UCF, and PCF), instance or
>   variable names that match internal reserved words are rejected unless
>   the names are enclosed in double quotes.

Constraint values, like pin names, are not placed in double quotes.

So the correct and recommended way should be

```
NET "input" LOC = N21
```